# Getting onStartChattingMessage to fire in a Kik bot

Tags: node.js, bots, kik

I have been playing around with the Kik bot framework using Node and have a bot to chat with. I am using the onTextMessage event successfully, but have yet to get the onStartChattingMessage to fire. The docs are not very detailed, any idea when this gets invoked? I thought it would be when I start a new chat with the bot but that doesn't seem to be it. Or I am just holding it wrong. Code is on GitHub at https://github.com/jcapka/otherword/blob/master/server.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/messaging#start-chatting this only happen

```
Under normal circumstances, you will receive this message once 
when user that starts chatting with you for the first time.
```

If you are trying to get it to work but using the original username you have already chatted.

You'd have to make a new account to be able to get the first-time experience and have that StartChattingmessage

As an example I went and messaged your bot and I got this response `

[image: Chat]

Comment: I see, I misunderstood and thought it would be at the start of each chat. Thanks for clearing this up. Much appreciate testing it out with the actual bot, nice to see it work.